# Can I speed up the laxative effect of coffee (maximum in 30-45 minutes)?

Tags: instant

- Hi everyone, I have a hydrogen-sulfur type SIBO disease and If I
  don't defecate everyday, the poop accumulates in the bowels and make
  me pass gas (believe me it has really foul smell like rotten egg). I
  everyday defecate through the laxative effects of the granular
  coffee.
- I put 3 teaspoon granular coffee, 3 cube sugar in every mug that I
  drink, and I drink 3 mug of coffee in total. If I don't add sugar in
  the coffee or I don't smoke cigaretts(it's too harmfull please don't
  smoke) with coffee or the coffee is cold, then the laxative effect of
  the coffee decrease too much(atleast for me).
- And my main problem is that I drink that much coffee to defecate but
  it takes 2 hours of mine. As an unemployed person, 2 hours is nothing
  for me but because I'll be in working life soon and 2 hours'll have
  a worth as gold for me.

**Question:** How can I decrease the time that I need for the coffee's laxative effect?

**What I tried for it:** I drank hot water instead of coffee(I drank 6-7 mug of water for the same effect) but it took same amount time. I think to decrease the amount of water in the mug and increase the amount of coffee but I don't know if it works.

Comment: This reminds me of a question I answered on a different SE site, in which the asker was *smoking a cigarette* to have the desired effect, and I recommended a cup of coffee as safer.  I can recommend going for a walk or similar moderate exercise to enhance your coffee's bowel stimulation.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be best to ask your gastroenterologist.

I have IBS, not SIBO, so the following might not be right for you, but my gastroenterologist recommended daily prebiotic fiber.

I mix Bulletproof InnerFuel Prebiotic fiber supplement into coffee or a smoothie. The company recommends starting small and building up to ≈2 scoops, but I've settled on less than 1 scoop.

There are many types of fiber, and people respond differently to them, so plan on experimenting with types and amounts.

Answer (score 0):

Would an espresso coffee help?

It's not clear which compound in coffee causes this reaction, but I have noticed a double espresso in the morning causes the expected reaction within half an hour.